# How to set default state in checkbox when it is not checked- React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I am trying to set the default value of the check box when the check box is unchecked

Initial state

```
  this.state = {
  checkbox: null,
}

<Checkbox
 onChange={this.ChangeValue}
 />

 ChangeValue= (event) => {
this.setState(
  (prevState) => ({
    checkbox: !prevState.checkbox,
  })
})
```

When I click on the checkbox it sets to true which is fine when I unselect/uncheck the checkbox I need to set it to the default state value(null) instead of false

Comment: You can also use `defaultValue={this.state.checkbox}` to fix an initial state.

Comment: @Pellay what if I need a false value based on some condition to say by default checkbox will be checked and if I remove that checkbox I should set the state as false?How can i achieve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the value to alternate between `true` and `null` that can be done like this:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  checkbox: prevState.checkbox ? null : true
});
```

Comment: what if I need a false value based on some condition to say by default checkbox will be checked and if I remove that checkbox I should set the state as false?How can i achieve this